# How can I change the Background drawable of my button with onclick in Android?

Tags: android, button, onclick, drawable

I have a button with a drawable XML Background

```
android:background="@drawable/greenbut"
```

and i want to change the Background to my `@drawable/yellowbut` by make an onclick on my button.

I tried it with this code, but it seems to be completely wrong. I cannot use the `setBackground Function`. Can you please help..?

```
public void colorChanger(View v)
{
    Button changeBut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    changeBut.setBackground(R.drawable.yellowbut);
    changeBut.isClickable();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
public void colorChanger(View v)
{
 Button changeBut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
 changeBut.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellowbut);
 changeBut.isClickable();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Its as simple as that just follow the code hope it will help

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Button changeBut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                button.setBackgroundColor(Color.yellow);
            }
        });
```

Comment: that probably work, but that doesn't change it to my other drawable element :)

Comment: @Noxmiles please make it a bit specific if you want to change the color of the button or the whole tile that contains the elements.

Comment: "i want to change the Background to my @drawable/yellowbut" is not interpretable.